# Sentence without a subject

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects

I have learned that each sentence needs to have a subject. In the sentence below, I don't need the subject or I can't identify it there. So, I add the subject using `there`.

Is the first sentence correct or better is the second? If the first sentence is correct, what is the subject then?

> In the table below is an error.

or

> In the table below, there is an error.

Comment: Your first example has subject-dependent inversion where the noun phrase "an error" is the subject and the preposition phrase "in the table below" is a locative complement.

Comment: So both sentences are correct?

Comment: Yes, both are possible, though I prefer the second for reasons of style

Comment: Wait.. what do you mean by 'error' here? A mistake? A mistake under a table? That doesn't make sense, IMO

Comment: @user178049 It clearly refers to a list or a table of contents, or some such thing, not a piece of furniture.

Comment: Yes, it is a table in an article.

Comment: @BillJ Oh, it's **in** the table.

Comment: @user178049 That's what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BillJ mentions in his comment, the first sentence is an example of *inversion* where the normal order of subject-verb is reversed.  In this case "an error" is the subject.  The sentence could be rephrased as follows:

> An error is in the table below.

The subject of the second example is the *existential placeholder* "there".  This has no real meaning, because the pronoun "there" does not refer to any actual noun.

Both sentences are fine. I would prefer to use "there" -- but that's a question of style, not grammar.